# How can increase Laravel Sanctum token length

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-sanctum

***I get a token it has 40 character random string like this...***

1|z5F4SMYZRxLo8ScUYMmnExdYtQoJ8eaftQevF0Pa

***And I want 240 character random string like this...***

1|nvbqwunxjyxujtnqnqcxzhintxyswmsjdunbmuhkifbncgrucxchzirgkybtbcadrjjtjunroewmpidxwiobcvimbolzcjlmeddvusgqzmcakffyzqllbzihnvbqwunxjyxujtnqnqcxzhintxyswmsjdunbmuhkifbncgrucxchzirgkybtbcadrjjtjunroewmpidxwiobcvimbolzcjlmeddvusgqzmcakffyzqllbzih

*Please help me for how to increase the length of the Laravel Sanctum Token*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Open file: `app/Models/User.php` then
2. Check if this file is used `Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens` trait
3. Override method: `createToken` like this:

   ```
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
   use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
   use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
   use Illuminate\Support\Str;
   use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
   use Laravel\Sanctum\NewAccessToken;

   class User extends Authenticatable
   {
       use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

       /**
        * The attributes that are mass assignable.
        *
        * @var string[]
        */
       protected $fillable = [
           'name',
           'email',
           'password',
       ];

       /**
        * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
        *
        * @var array
        */
       protected $hidden = [
           'password',
           'remember_token',
       ];

       /**
        * The attributes that should be cast.
        *
        * @var array
        */
       protected $casts = [
           'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
       ];

       /**
        * Create a new personal access token for the user.
        *
        * @param  string  $name
        * @param  array  $abilities
        * @return \Laravel\Sanctum\NewAccessToken
        */
       public function createToken(string $name, array $abilities = ['*'])
       {
           $token = $this->tokens()->create([
               'name' => $name,
               'token' => hash('sha256', $plainTextToken = Str::random(240)),
               'abilities' => $abilities,
           ]);

           return new NewAccessToken($token, $token->getKey().'|'.$plainTextToken);
       }
     }
   ```

You can use:

```
$user->createToken('your name token')->plainTextToken;
```